# how to show youtube comment profile pic in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, youtube-data-api

i want to show youtube user's comment section profile pic in my wordpress comment section

As i am fetching youtube video along with its commnets but i couldn't show user's profile image in my comment section in my blog

comment i fetched with profile pic
[image: in my admin panel]

in blog comment section its showing blank or default image gravatar
[image: in cooment section]

url i got for author

```
https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRFowb1wyXwkxTIi3UgCrpJlBxZJuP4WLA9vK6f=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj|
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just appended at the end a '|' (vertical bar) to the URL you got from an author otherwise the URL leads to a customized avatar cf https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRFowb1wyXwkxTIi3UgCrpJlBxZJuP4WLA9vK6f=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj

Comment: can you tell me how to do it, as all the comments url like this, i am using wp-automatic plugin

Comment: I'm not keen on wordpress, I show you the problem, now just see how to remove the last character of a string or remove a given character ('|'). Note: give code how you retrieve this URL if you want me to try to help you with it.